# container not available in Symfony AbstractFixtures

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fixtures

I need to create fixtures for a « complex » system : many entities involved.

I'm using a CMS using Doctrine Fixtures, so i choose to use for that purpose the AbstractFixtures which is available , allowing me to pass references from a fixture to another with $this->getReference () ...

I [followed the docs for Abstract fixtures](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures) since i needed sharing objects and then the other paragraph [for using container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#using-the-container-in-the-fixtures) :

```
namespace NWA\SocBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use NWA\SocBundle\Entity\Resource\ResourceNode;

class LoadResourceData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface
{
    private $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $guid = $this->container->get('my.service.name')->generateGuid();
    ...
       //my fixture logic here, using the value $guid at some point
}
```

I have the error : **Error: Call to a member function get() on null**

Where can it come from ?

The container should be available (since the class implements ContainerAwareInterface) ?

**----  Edit ----**

1 - I'm using the "dev-master" version of "doctrine/data-fixture"

2 - I can't see how i can use ContainerAware directly since AFAIK i can't use multiple heritage : i can't do

`class LoadResourceData extends AbstractFixture, ContainerAware implements OrderedFixtureInterface`

3 - i obviously can't use `$this->container` alone (without implementing ContainerAwareInterface) since AbstractFixture doesn't use `$this->container`

Comment: Which versions of the DoctrineFixturesBundle and the `doctrine/data-fixtures` package do you use?

Comment: Implementing the ContainerAwareInterface does not by itself cause the container to be injected.  Something still needs to call setContainer.  Show how you are creating the LoadResourceData instance.  And off topic but consider just injecting your 'my.service' instead of the complete container.

Comment: I agree to say there is something strange somewhere, but can you test in removing the `setContainer()`, the `private $container`, the `ContainerAwareInterface`, and just implement by `ContainerAware` ? **ContainerAware includes the $container itself** ...

Comment: I stand corrected.  doctrine:fixtures:load should inject the container.  Which version are you using?